# Angular and Material Multi-level Menu with Breadcrumb not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, breadcrumbs, angular-material-6

I am working with angular 6 and angular material 6. Here i am trying to create multilevel menu with breadcrumb. I have worked multilevel menu with properly but can not able to navigate menu with selected breadcrumb. When i click on the selected breadcrumb then the menu not getting organized appropriately.

My demo link : [stackblitz link here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multilevel-menu-with-breadcrumb-eh7ngk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@hi Monir tuhin

You can try this Solution.

I Have create a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-and-material-multi-level-menu-with-breadcrumb-not-worki?file=src/app/app.component.html).

> Component.ts

```
breadCrumb(menu, index) {
    console.log('sub breadCrumb');
    this.menuHeader.splice(index + 1, this.menuHeader.length - 1);
    if (menu[index] && menu[index].items && menu[index].items.length) {
      this.appitemsTravel = menu[index].items;
    }
}
```

> Component.html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" style="height: 45px; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #E6E8EA">
    <span><a  mat-button (click)="breadCrumbMain()" style="color: white;">Main</a></span>
    <span *ngFor="let m of menuHeader; let indx = index" style="color: white;">
        <a  mat-button (click)="breadCrumb(menuHeader, indx)" >{{m.label}}
        <mat-icon fxFlex="10">{{m.icon}}</mat-icon></a>
    </span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks again @Krishna Rathore. You have done great work. I have tried a lot of times but could not able to fix it. You save my lot of times.

Answer (score 3):

@Krishna Rathore thank you very much for your solution.
I just changed a few things:

- used the material sidenav and material nav list;
- icons as the breadcrumbs;
- also possible to use font-awesome icons.

Here is the forked [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-multi-level-menu-with-breadcrumb).

Thought I should post here to give you the credits and to help anyone that comes along.